# jQuery Draggable Randomly Broken?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

A while back, I made a page on my site that uses jQuery, which has divs on it that are resizable and draggable. In the past it has worked flawlessly:

http://8wayrun.com/streams/multi?type=1&pos1=1.v.8wayrun&pos2=1.c.8wayrun

This is the code I've been using:

```
$('#position_'+position).resizable({
    animate: true,
    handles: 'e, s, w, se, sw',
    helper: 'multiBlank-helper',
    start: function( event, ui ) { $('.multiBlank').append('<div class="overlay"></div>'); },
    stop: function( event, ui ) { $('.multiBlank .overlay').remove(); },
}).draggable({
    handle: '.info',
    opacity: 0.75,
    snap: true,
    snapTolerance: 10,
    stack: { group: '.multiBlank', min: 100 },
    start: function( event, ui ) { $('.multiBlank').append('<div class="overlay"></div>'); },
    stop: function( event, ui ) { $('.multiBlank .overlay').remove(); },
});
```

However, I find out today that its no longer working. The elements are still resizable without any issues. But when I try to drag them arround I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
```

I dont know exactly when it broke. But I'm assuming it was with a past upgrade to jQuery. Can anyone help me figure this out and what I need to do to get it working again?

Comment: in what part of the code is `defaultView` property used? it seems this is where  you should start

Comment: Thats just the thing... I have no idea what `defaultView` is; I dont use it in any of my code.

Comment: probably it is used by some other library you use in your project, try find out

Comment: it is probably from ember.js library as it uses MVC pattern and views

Comment: What I'm saying is that I never changed my project, except for upgrading to more recent versions of jQuery. I have no idea what `defaultView` is or what is calling it. So I have no idea where to even start looking.

Comment: and ember is part of twitch? If I replace the embeds with embeds from a different service, its still broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... apparently the usage of `stack` in the draggable function has changed:

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack

It no longer takes a set of variables, but a single variable. Changing the variable to be more in-line with the new usage fixed the error.